# Template class derived from private member class breaks encapsulation

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I've found what appears to be a strange method to break encapsulation of a class derived within a class

take the following

```cpp
class Base
{
    private:
        class Member
        {
            public:
                virtual ~Member() {}

                virtual void Function() = 0;
         };
};
```

if you try to derive from this private class

```cpp
class DerivedMember : public Base::Member
{
    public:
        DerivedMember() {}

        virtual void Function() {/*Do something*/}
};
```

you get a compile error

```
error: 'class Base::Member' is private
error: within this context
```

however if you derive from it a template

```cpp
template <typename T>
class TemplateDerivedMember : public Base::Member
{
    public:
        TemplateDerivedMember () {}

        virtual void Function() {/*Do something*/}
};
```

then the compiler will accept it, and allow this to happen.

i've tested this against GCC 8.1 and GCC 4.6, and both have the same behaviour.
is this a bug, or is it something that should be allowed? does deriving it as a template class implicitly place the `TemplateDerivedMember` class as a member of `Base`? (it doesn't appear to as it accessible in the global namespace)

Comment: Seems like a bug with gcc: it accepts the code regardless of whether the template is instantiated. Interestingly, Clang rejects regardless of whether the template is instantiated, while MSVC rejects only when it is instantiated. Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/t2nI14

Comment: There are other ways of breaking access control via templates; does this one matter?

Comment: it may not be the only one, but it depends if it is a bug, as opposed to UB, or a defined method to break it. if the compilers implement it differently, it's possibly not a standardised thing, or even part of the standard.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin: with small variations, they all wait for instantiation [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/JLK71G) (but gcc still accepts it [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TkpDkF))

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a bug, which apparently was fixed since GCC 11. Both Clang and MSVC always rejected the code as far as I can see. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9evfYq5hc